# Excel & VBA - Linest function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset (x,y):
(1,64; 1,34) (2,64; 1,54) (4,74;2,23) (7,63;    2,51)

I want to do a polynomial regression in VBA - so I wrote a bit of code:

```
varr = Application.LinEst(Range(Cells(5, 17), Cells(5 + (y - 1), 17)), Application.Power(Range(Cells(5, 16), Cells(5 + (y - 1), 16)), Array(1, 2)), False, True)
```

Now, with the polynomial regression I get the parameters right, but the r^2 seems totally wrong.

In my array varr, r^2  located at varr(3,1) - I do get a number.. but its wrong. When I do a "normal" chart in excel - same data, I get r^2=0,919 while my code gets me an R^2=0,995152656703383

What is going on?

Comment: I get the same Rsq value in Excel as your code. What formula are you using to test in Excel?

Comment: I use the graphing function, adding a trendline; polynomial second order with intercept=0,0)

Comment: I get different values when i just calculate manually in excel with =LINEST(Q5:Q8;P5:P8^{1,2};FALSE;TRUE). I get the following matrix: (0,2708;   -) ;   
 (0,0559;  #N/A);
 (0,8865 ;  0,7643); 
 (23,4312;   3,0000 )
 (13,6877 ;  1,7525)

Comment: I get: `{-0.0577799890803959,0.765096434024781,0;0.0110009856902354,0.0727395739535586,#N/A;0.995152656703383,0.193447602684072,#N/A}` using the values you supplied (Excel 2010)

Comment: Excel gives the wrong r2 when you set the trendline's intercept to zero --- see (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/829249)

Comment: @Soren Christensen Were you able to verify the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The chart R-squared value includes rounding error. If you calculate R-Squared manually using the equation displayed on the chart, the answer is .919.